# How to do a regex match on 1-1/2 inch

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a one and a half inch match using regex.

For example, if I have a term "1-1/2 inch", I would like to recognize "1-1/2" as a group and " inch" as another group. The regex shuold also work for half inch ("1/2 inch"). How do I do this?

I tried the below expression:
([0-9]{1,4}.*-*/*)\s*(?:inches|inch|ins|in.\sL|in.|in|\")*

But it doesn't work properly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a few more examples of input and the groups you want to capture from each of them?

Answer (score 0):

## Python code

The main problem is in the first part where you want to match 1-1/2 or 1/2. Just approach it the same way as you did for Inch, Inches, inch, inches, asnd so on.

```
import re
line = "1/2 ins"
matchObj = re.match( r'(1-1/2|1/2)\s(Inches|inch|ins|in)', line, re.M|re.I)
if matchObj:
   print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
   print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
   print "matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2)
else:
   print "No match!!"
```